# Similar XML doens't run in the same XSLT

Tags: xml, excel, xslt

thanks in advance i have a quick question that's been killing my head for the last 4 hours..

I have this XSLT

```
  <xsl:when test="NAME='IES_ObtemBeneficiosEmpregados2'">
    <Worksheet ss:Name="Gastos_Pessoal">
      <Table>
        <ss:Column ss:Width="400"/>
        <ss:Column ss:Width="100"/>
        <Row ss:Index="1">
          <Cell ss:Index="1" >
            <Data ss:Type="String">RÚBRICAS
            </Data>
          </Cell>
          <Cell ss:Index="2" >
            <Data ss:Type="String">Valor
            </Data>
          </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row ss:Index="2">
          <Cell ss:Index="1"  >
            <Data ss:Type="String">Gastos com o Pessoal
            </Data>
          </Cell>
          <Cell ss:Index="2" >
            <Data ss:Type="String">
              <xsl:value-of select="VALUES/ROW/GastosComPessoal"/>
            </Data>
          </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row ss:Index="3">
          <Cell ss:Index="1"  >
            <Data ss:Type="String">Remunerações dos orgãos sociais
            </Data>
          </Cell>
          <Cell ss:Index="2" >
            <Data ss:Type="String">
              <xsl:value-of select="VALUES/ROW/RemuneracoesOrgaosSociais"/>
            </Data>
          </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row ss:Index="4">
          <Cell ss:Index="1"  >
            <Data ss:Type="String">Participação nos lucros
            </Data>
          </Cell>
          <Cell ss:Index="2" >
            <Data ss:Type="String">
              <xsl:value-of select="VALUES/ROW/ComParticipacaoNosLucros"/>
            </Data>
          </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row ss:Index="5">
          <Cell ss:Index="1"  >
            <Data ss:Type="String">Remunerações do pessoal
            </Data>
          </Cell>
          <Cell ss:Index="2" >
            <Data ss:Type="String">
              <xsl:value-of select="VALUES/ROW/RemuneracoesPessoal"/>
            </Data>
          </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row ss:Index="6">
          <Cell ss:Index="1"  >
            <Data ss:Type="String">pós emprego
            </Data>
          </Cell>
          <Cell ss:Index="2" >
            <Data ss:Type="String">
              <xsl:value-of select="VALUES/ROW/BeneficiosPosEmprego"/>
            </Data>
          </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row ss:Index="7">
          <Cell ss:Index="1"  >
            <Data ss:Type="String">Prémios para pensões
            </Data>
          </Cell>
          <Cell ss:Index="2" >
            <Data ss:Type="String">
              <xsl:value-of select="VALUES/ROW/PremiosParaPensoes"/>
            </Data>
          </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row ss:Index="8">
          <Cell ss:Index="1"  >
            <Data ss:Type="String">Outros beneficios
            </Data>
          </Cell>
          <Cell ss:Index="2" >
            <Data ss:Type="String">
              <xsl:value-of select="VALUES/ROW/OutrosBeneficios"/>
            </Data>
          </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row ss:Index="9">
          <Cell ss:Index="1"  >
            <Data ss:Type="String">Planos de contribuições definidas pelos orgãos sociais
            </Data>
          </Cell>
          <Cell ss:Index="2" >
            <Data ss:Type="String">
              <xsl:value-of select="VALUES/ROW/PlanosOrgaosSociais"/>
            </Data>
          </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row ss:Index="10">
          <Cell ss:Index="1"  >
            <Data ss:Type="String">Planos de contribuições definidas por outros
            </Data>
          </Cell>
          <Cell ss:Index="2" >
            <Data ss:Type="String">
              <xsl:value-of select="VALUES/ROW/PlanosAOutros"/>
            </Data>
          </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row ss:Index="11">
          <Cell ss:Index="1"  >
            <Data ss:Type="String">Indemnizações
            </Data>
          </Cell>
          <Cell ss:Index="2" >
            <Data ss:Type="String">
              <xsl:value-of select="VALUES/ROW/Indemnizacoes"/>
            </Data>
          </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row ss:Index="12">
          <Cell ss:Index="1"  >
            <Data ss:Type="String">Encargos sobre remunerações
            </Data>
          </Cell>
          <Cell ss:Index="2" >
            <Data ss:Type="String">
              <xsl:value-of select="VALUES/ROW/Encargos"/>
            </Data>
          </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row ss:Index="13">
          <Cell ss:Index="1"  >
            <Data ss:Type="String">Seguros de acidentes de trabalho e doenças profissionais
            </Data>
          </Cell>
          <Cell ss:Index="2" >
            <Data ss:Type="String">
              <xsl:value-of select="VALUES/ROW/Seguros"/>
            </Data>
          </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row ss:Index="14">
          <Cell ss:Index="1"  >
            <Data ss:Type="String">Gastos de acção social
            </Data>
          </Cell>
          <Cell ss:Index="2" >
            <Data ss:Type="String">
              <xsl:value-of select="VALUES/ROW/GastosDeAccaoSocial"/>
            </Data>
          </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row ss:Index="15">
          <Cell ss:Index="1"  >
            <Data ss:Type="String">Outros gastos com pessoal
            </Data>
          </Cell>
          <Cell ss:Index="2" >
            <Data ss:Type="String">
              <xsl:value-of select="VALUES/ROW/OutrosGastos"/>
            </Data>
          </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row ss:Index="16">
          <Cell ss:Index="1"  >
            <Data ss:Type="String">DOS QUAIS
            </Data>
          </Cell>
          <Cell ss:Index="2" >
          </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row ss:Index="17">
          <Cell ss:Index="1"  >
            <Data ss:Type="String">Gastos com formação
            </Data>
          </Cell>
          <Cell ss:Index="2" >
            <Data ss:Type="String">
              <xsl:value-of select="VALUES/ROW/GastosComFormacao"/>
            </Data>
          </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row ss:Index="18">
          <Cell ss:Index="1"  >
            <Data ss:Type="String">Gastos com fardamento
            </Data>
          </Cell>
          <Cell ss:Index="2" >
            <Data ss:Type="String">
              <xsl:value-of select="VALUES/ROW/GastosComFardamento"/>
            </Data>
          </Cell>
        </Row>
      </Table>
    </Worksheet>

  </xsl:when>
```

Why does this Xslt can run this xml

```
<MODULO>
    <NAME>IES_ObtemBeneficiosEmpregados2</NAME>
    <VALUES>
      <ROW>
        <BeneficiosPosEmprego>0.00</BeneficiosPosEmprego>
        <ComParticipacaoNosLucros />
        <Encargos>227318.12</Encargos>
        <GastosComFardamento>9382.88</GastosComFardamento>
        <GastosComFormacao />
        <GastosComPessoal>1404365.80</GastosComPessoal>
        <GastosDeAccaoSocial />
        <Indemnizacoes />
        <OSComParticipacaoNosLucros />
        <OutrosBeneficios />
        <OutrosGastos>88327.73</OutrosGastos>
        <PlanosAOutros />
        <PlanosOrgaosSociais />
        <PremiosParaPensoes />
        <RemuneracoesOrgaosSociais />
        <RemuneracoesPessoal>1082034.06</RemuneracoesPessoal>
        <Seguros>6685.89</Seguros>
      </ROW>
    </VALUES>
  </MODULO>
```

But not this XML which has the same Tags/fields/Names just different Values

```
  <MODULO>
    <NAME>IES_ObtemBeneficiosEmpregados2</NAME>
    <VALUES>
      <ROW>
        <BeneficiosPosEmprego>0.00</BeneficiosPosEmprego>
        <ComParticipacaoNosLucros />
        <Encargos>3115950.69</Encargos>
        <GastosComFardamento />
        <GastosComFormacao />
        <GastosComPessoal>18012189.63</GastosComPessoal>
        <GastosDeAccaoSocial>504655.34</GastosDeAccaoSocial>
        <Indemnizacoes>47764.83</Indemnizacoes>
        <OSComParticipacaoNosLucros />
        <OutrosBeneficios />
        <OutrosGastos>55628.15</OutrosGastos>
        <PlanosAOutros />
        <PlanosOrgaosSociais />
        <PremiosParaPensoes />
        <RemuneracoesOrgaosSociais />
        <RemuneracoesPessoal>13937277.03</RemuneracoesPessoal>
        <Seguros>350913.59</Seguros>
      </ROW>
    </VALUES>
  </MODULO>
```

I honestly don't see what's the problem with the code, it has been running 100% fine while i was testing with it, now im trying a different XML and it just stoped working , both these XML are generated through a stored procedure in SQL so there's no way the Tags are different.

EDIT:

The error it gives me is always the same ,

```
<h1>The object reference was not defined as an instance of an object</h1>
```

This shows up only when i open the Excel file created by the XSLT.

I was not clear enough when first asking the question.
Both these XML's are not run at the same time , they are automaticaly generated by a stored that creates a big XML file (Around 5000 lines) and then this XML runs through the XSLT (which i provided a small piece above) And then it gives me a Excel file. I already did all the bits of the XSLT and its working fine for 1 instance , but when i try to generate a differente report, it just blows up in that bit of code ( i know that by trial and error by removing bits of the XSLT to see where it was blowing up) .

After all this i still have no idea why Similar pieces of XML (only with differente values inside the tags) are being interpreted differently.

Comment: When you say "it stopped working", please describe the symptoms. Did it just blow up in a puff of smoke, or did it produce any output?

Comment: Your XPaths are relative to some other node/element `VALUES/ROW/GastosComPessoal`. That's because it doesn't start with an slash or double slash. Check if parent tag has changed.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the replies!
I think i was not clear enough when i asked the question, i'll edit a bit !

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it would really help if you post the **complete XSL** into your questions instead of just a `when` block. We have no idea what the rest of your XSL does.

Having said that, I see two obvious problems:

- In your XSL code I see no `<ss:Workbook>` element that should be around the `<ss:Worksheet>` element. But perhaps it is part of the not posted XSL code
- You really have to **fix your namespaces!** The only element in the `ss:` namespace is `<ss:Column>`. But `Worksheet`, `Table`, `Row`, `Cell` and `Data` also belong to this namespace.